# Rails - email link validation and phone number validation with URL validation

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, validation, email, url

I am using this code for **URL validation**.

```
def url?(string)
  uri = URI.parse(string)
  !uri.host.nil?
rescue URI::BadURIError
  false
rescue URI::InvalidURIError
  false
end
```

This works but I also want to validate **email links** and **phone number links**.

For example

```
mailto:test@gmail.com
tel:1234567890
```

I don't want to include **email validation** and **phone number validation**.

Anyone can help me?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Are you looking for this -

```
def url?(string)
  uri = URI.parse(string)
  throw "MailToError" if uri.scheme == 'mailto'
  throw "TelError" if uri.scheme == 'tel'
  !uri.host.nil?
rescue URI::BadURIError
  false
rescue URI::InvalidURIError
  false
rescue => e
  !(e.to_s.include?("TelError") || e.to_s.include?("MailToError"))
end
```